# What do we do with all the coal mines?

Tags: energy, climate-change, coal

Coal is going to be the first victim of the green energy revolution as the least sustainable kind of fossil fuel. What do we do with all the mines, both surface and underground ones? You can do quite a few things (e.g. [flood](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20210706-how-flooded-coal-mines-could-heat-homes) them and pump that warm water to heat homes or [turn](http://www.premiercoal.com.au/page/sustainability/environment/lake-kepwari/) them into lakes), but what are the best upscaleable options that could handle thousands of mines about to shut down in a few years or, at most, decades' time? Don't forget about the people employed by the coal industry. I guess you can retrain former miners into photovoltaic engineers but you're unlikely to succeed in doing so on a large scale. How to make use of decommissioned coal mines, globally, in a way that is both environmentally and socially beneficial?

Comment: Eastern Germany turns some former pit mines into recreational areas after securing the walls of the pit and flooding them partially.

Comment: @Erik  you. expound that, please? Turning a nminem into n recreational area sounds wonderful… but how?

Comment: @robbiegoodwin the same way as in the case of lake Kepwari, I guess

Comment: Really? Other than perhaps large areas, what similarities do you see between lakes and mines?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Lake Kepwari used to be a mine, then they flooded it and turned it into a recreational area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abandoned underground coal mines present a potential hazard to anyone who might enter them. The first hazard is fugitive methane gas and the second is coal dust. Under the right conditions, both can be explosive.

Because of fugitive methane emissions it would be best for underground coal mines to be allowed to flood and to be sealed to prevent entry to the underground voids. Whether flooding is possible depends on the location of the water table and any aquifers in relation to the coal seams.

The state of any abandoned underground coal mine will depend on the mining method used to mine the coal, when the mine was operating. Room and pillar methods, also known as bord and pillar, leave some of the coal behind as pillars, to support the overlying rock and the mined voids between the pillars are generally left open.

The other significant coal mining method is/was longwall where highly mechanized coal cutting machines cut long walls of coal. The cut coal is loaded onto conveyor belts to be sent out of the mine. While cutting the coal the immediate region is supported by hydraulic shields. All this equipment moves automatically as the coal face advances. The void left behind is required to collapse. If it doesn't special teams of people induce failure of the overlying rock, behind the hydraulic shields.

This leaves a rubble pile of various sized boulders filling the void. Ultimately the overlying rock unravels to fill the void and in doing so the land surface will experience subsidence.

Back in the 1980s and 1990s, Poland used to orientate the longwalls so surface subsidence would be uniform and occur at the same time so that entire villages would sink intact, without damaging any of the buildings - particularly centuries old churches. How successful this process was I don't know.

Such a broken, porous terrain will easily allow fugitive methane emissions to be released. Sometimes coal seams occur in groups of various thicknesses and quality of coal. The interburden of non coal sedimentary rock between the coal seam can also vary in thickness. Usually the "best quality" and "most profitable" coal is mined. The other seams remain as they are. Methane emissions can occurs from such seams.

Allowing the mines to flood would minimize much of the fugitive methane emissions.

As for open cut coal mines, it largely depends on how the coal has been mine as to what can be done. Some open cut coal mines are already backfill, during the course of mining, with the waste overburned from the new region to be mined filling the mined out region next to it. This occurs when draglines are used to strip the waste overburden.

Mines that use bucket wheel excavators, such as many in Germany, are generally backfilled by other means. In other regions of the world, such mines are left unfilled. If the water table is high enough, such pits will fill with water to form artificial lakes.

As for the people who would have worked in the coal mines the world needs to do better than Britain did when it shut its coal mines during the 1980s and also abandoned the people and the towns to largely fend for themselves. Many of those regions are still suffering.

---

***Edit*** - Additional information

With some open pit coal mines the amount of waste over burden, lying on top of the coal can be thin and the coal seam thick. In such situations, there isn't enough overburden to completely fill the resulting pit. Unless other forms of backfill can be utilized the "rehabilitated" pit will always have a depression within it, compared to the natural setting prior to mining.

Another use for some open pit coal mines is to use them as landfill rubbish site for domestic rubbish.

---

***Edit 6 January 2022***
I recently came across this BBC news for a second time, *[How flooded coal mines could heat homes](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20210706-how-flooded-coal-mines-could-heat-homes)*. The title of the news item self descriptive.

Apparently in the United Kingdom a quarter of the homes sit above abandoned coal mines, now flooded with water. It is estimated there is 2 billion cubic meters of water with these underground coal mines. It is also estimated the amount of heat these waters contain is 2.2 million GWh.

Using geothermal consultants from Iceland a scheme has been devised where the warm waters within the mines can be used to provide heating on a large scale. The temperature of the water is apparently steady throughout the entire year.

> the Coal Authority is exploring the feasibility of some 70 mine water heating projects across the UK.

Since 2008 a similar scheme has been operating in the Netherlands where is supplies heat to,

> 500 houses and commercial facilities, serving over 250,000 sq m (2.7 million sq ft) of building space.

How applicable such a scheme would be elsewhere would be dependent on the depth of the mines, the geothermal gradient at those locations and hence the temperature of the water within the mines and how the heat could be used on the surface. In some locations, such as Australia and South Africa, some of the mines are not located under urban or industrial landscape but under rural and semi wilderness landscapes remote from established or permanent towns or cities.

Comment: I guess a better phrasing would be "How to make use of decommissioned coal mines in a way that is both environmentally and socially beneficial?"

Answer (score 0):

For decades the US has required surface mines to filled with spoils ( removed material) and graded to resemble original topography and planted with local trees, etc. Underground mines pretty much fill with water naturally so entrances need to be sealed to prevent anyone from entering. Two problems, coal mines always have methane gas and you don't want it to build up pressure. Clarification; if a coal field is flooded the methane is not released. To produce gas from the Black Warrior (US) coal basin, water must first be pumped out of the coal strata.  And a mine may catch fire; some are now burning in US and I have read that many are burning in China and else where.  The fires are difficult to control because of air access points that are unknown. The good news is the UN IPCC does not count the CO2 from burning coal mines as "man made" so it does not contribute to anthropogenic global warming.